# How do I save a N x M array/list using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, save

I have a `N x M` numpy array / list. I want to save this matrix into a `.csv` file using Pandas. Unfortunately I don't know **a priori** the values of M and N which can be *large*. I am interested in Pandas because I find it manageable in terms of data columns access.

Let's start with this MWE:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N,M = np.random.randint(10,100, size = 2)
A = np.random.randint(10, size = (N,M))

columns = []

for i in range(len(A[0,:])):
   columns.append( "column_{} ".format(i)  )
```

I cannot do something like `pd.append( )` i.e. appending columns with new additional indices via a for loop.

Is there a way to save A into a .csv file?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(A).to_csv('yourfile.csv')`?

Comment: Also, why don't you use `np.save/load`?

Comment: @QuangHoang Because I didn't know the existence of these commands. Please rearrange this/these comment/s into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comment of Quang Hoang, there are 2 possibilities:

1. `pd.DataFrame(A).to_csv('yourfile.csv')`.
2. `np.save("yourfile.npy",A)` and then `A = np.load("yourfile.npy")`.